# Проблема с выборкой и модулем json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не получается выбрать все элементы из словаря по заданному критерию,
и добавить их в строку.
Выбирается только последний, но он только и добавляется.

```
import json
import datetime

load_data = open("todos.json", 'r+')
data = json.load(load_data)
load_data.close()
now_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M")



for i in data:
    new_id = i.get('userId')
    completed_work = ""
    not_completed = ""
    if i.get('completed') == True:
        completed_work += str(i.get('title'))
    else:
        not_completed += str(i.get('title'))
    new_file = open(f"{new_id}_{now_time}.txt", 'w+', encoding="utf-8")
    new_file.write(f"#Сотрудник №{new_id}\n{now_time}\n\n## Завершенные задачи: {completed_work}\n## Оставшиеся задачи: {not_completed}")
    new_file.close()
```

Comment: w+ Открывает файл для чтения и записи. Указатель стоит в начале файла. Создает файл с именем имя_файла, если такового не существует. - вы просто переписываете файл каждый цикл

Comment: Поменяйте на a+ Открывает файл для добавления и чтения. Указатель стоит в конце файла. Создает файл с именем имя_файла, если такового не существует.

Comment: тот случай, когда уже по заголовку понятно, что файл открывается не в том режиме или не в том месте :)

Comment: @Эникейщик нет, место как бы и то, а вот режим - не верный

Comment: @splash58 Да почему, можно же открыть перед циклом, а закрыть после.

Comment: можно, только сделать словарь по сотрудникам

Comment: пример todos.json и ожидаемого .txt добавьте, пожалуйста?

Comment: @splash58, спасибо. Поменял режим и все теперь добавляется логически верно. Осталось сделать, чтобы "Завершенные дела" и "Оставшиеся дела" шли просто строкой, а не дописывались всем абзацем.

Comment: @Jack_oS Спасибо. Метод splash58 мне помог. Я изменил режим на "a+" и все заработало.

Comment: @Jack_oS Вот так выглядит todos.js: `[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  }, ` А вывод txt должен быть таким: 1 строка - Сотрудник №(тут id), 2 строка время, 3 строка пусто, 4 строка ## Завершенные дела, 5 строка ## Оставшиеся дела